# Does SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 2.0)removes the node from the scene or just "hides" it?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I'm making a game and I fade out a node, but I don't know if it is removed from the scene or it is just hidden. I want to add another node at the exact same place and I do not want to have nodes over each other.

```
let fadeOutAction = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 2.0)
nodeToFadeOut.run(fadeOutAction)
```

This works perfect but I do not know if the node is removed from the scene.

Comment: It's still there unless you literally remove it from the scene.

Comment: So i have to perform node.removeFromParent() ?

Comment: If you need to remove it from the scene, yes.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but isn't it also really easy to answer this for yourself? Simply run it and then do a `print(!node is \(fadedNode)")`. Or refer to the SKAction docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417738-fadeout). Being new to sprite-Kit, you will need to be able to verify things like this for yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is something that you may find useful :)

```
func fadeAndRemove(node: SKNode) {
  let fadeOutAction = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 2.0)
  let remove        = SKAction.run({ node.removeFromParent }())
  let sequence      = SKAction.sequence([fadeOutAction, remove])
  node.run(sequence)
}

fadeAndRemove(node: myCoolSpriteNode)
```

You can verify this multiple ways, but the easiest is to just look at the node count on the bottom right of your screen:

[image]

My node count started at 4, then dropped to 3 after 2 seconds :)

Comment: I use it like extension of SKNode